# build error "Failed to capture snapshot of input files" for task ':preReleaseBuild

Tags: cordova, gradle, cordova-android

I am getting the following error when trying to build my cordova android app

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':preReleaseBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.> 1**

I have clean the project (cordova clean) but I still get the same issue

Can you please give me some hints on how to resolve this issue?

My gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build-gradle extra

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
            google()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
    }
}
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Additional info..

-- cordova CLI to build (cordova build android)
-- using mac to build
-- angular cordova app

Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
  browser 5.0.3
  ios 4.5.5

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

Just clean and re-initialize everything.  Specifically:

```
cd $MYPROJECT
rm -rf node_modules (or Windows equivalent)
gradle clean
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error. I have done what you have suggested . Also, remove the platform and re-add but the error still exist

Comment: Drag.  Q: Are you using the command line, or an IDE?  If IDE, are you using the gradle that's integrated with the IDE? Are you on Windows or Linux?  Are you using Ionic2 (and Angular)?  Or React? Or just "vanilla  Cordova"?

Comment: Thanks.. I updated the question with the information requested

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Mac, so I can't help much further.  SUGGESTIONS:1) It couldn't hurt to clear your Gradle cache, 2) Try to get as much additional info as possible (e.g. `cordova build --verbose`), 3) Revisit each version# in each dependency in your build.grade, 4) Look [here](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/issues/280) and [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/conflict-between-two-libraries/7209)